# How to reference internal and external module from one file/directory

Tags: typescript, protractor

is there anyway where i can place all my reference module internal as well as external and use it from that place.

```
import {browser, element, by, By, ElementFinder,ElementArrayFinder} from "protractor";

import {FactoryRegistry} from "./../../../factories/FactoryRegistry";

import {TableActionParams} from "./../../../actionHandlers/Actions";

import {TableActions} from "./../../../actionHandlers/Enums";

let helpers = require("protractor-helpers");
import {FactoryRegistry} from "./../../factories/FactoryRegistry";
import {browser,element,by,By, ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder} from "protractor";
var fs=require('fs')

var system = require('util')

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var fs_extra = require('fs-extra');
```

So is there any way where i can place all these require and export and call them in our script.

We are using protractor with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just make a single file called `helpers.js` or whatever you would like.  Add all of the above `require` statements into that new file, and then you simply export that file and require it in your tests/configs.  I don't use Typescript so your syntax may be slightly different.

Helper file (helper.js):

```
module.exports = {
    system: require('util'),
    exec: require('child_process').exec,
    fs_extra: require('fs-extra')
};
```

Include the helpers as a global in your config so they are accessible from your tests:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    global.helpers = require('helpers.js');
}
```

Then in your spec, include whatever ones you need for this specific test:

```
var system = helpers.system
```

Or, if you dont want to do the global route via your config file.  Simply require that file into your specs.

```
var helpers = require('helpers.js');
var system = helpers.system;
```

Comment: This wont work in the Typescript for the Import as it will show the compile error.
I can't write 
 let abc=import {browser, element, by, By, ElementFinder,ElementArrayFinder} from "protractor";